# Warning about pthread_t pointer conversion

Tags: c, pthreads

I made this test code to try to pass the pthread_t of thread2 to thread1, and made the code that let `main thread` wait `thread1` finish  than `thread1` wait `thread2` finish:

```
   void *function_thread1(void *ptr){
      pthread_t thread2;
      thread2 = (pthread_t *)ptr;
      printf("the end of the thread1\n");
      pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
      pthread_exit(0);

    }

void *function_thread2(void *ptr){
  printf("the end of the thread2\n");
  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(void){
  pthread_t thread1,thread2;
  pthread_t *ptr2;
  ptr2 = &thread2;
  pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,function_thread2,(void*) ptr2);
  pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,function_thread1,NULL);
  printf("This is the end of main thread\n");
  pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
  exit(0);
}
```

It works, but I got the following warning that I don't know :

```
thread_join.c:12:10: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
      assigning to 'pthread_t' (aka 'unsigned long') from 'pthread_t *'
      (aka 'unsigned long *'); dereference with *
        thread2 = (pthread_t *)ptr;
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  *
1 warning generated.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are passing the wrong functions in the calls to pthread_create. function_thread1 will be called with a NULL argument and your code will (hopefully) segfault.

Comment: Also, you code contains a race condition: In function_thread1 (at `thread2 = (pthread_t *)ptr;`) *ptr  will only contain something meaningful if the second call to phtread_create finished before function_thread1 reaches this point.

Comment: @MauganRa thanks for pointing out the race condition, I should study on this subject soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
pthread_t *thread2;
thread2 = ptr;

pthread_join(*thread2, NULL);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! BTW why I can't use `pthread_join(*ptr, NULL)` directly

Comment: @yozloy You can't dereference `void *`.